# To the point of time

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> This **closed-gap solution** can help to bridge the gap between now **to
>   the point of time** where the real solution is discovered.

1. Is **closed-gap solution** the right word to use for tentative solution?
2. Is **to the point of time** grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: There is a gap between two things. It should say *"... bridge the gap between now **and** the point ..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "This closed-gap solution" isn't an idiomatic expression. I suggest "interim solution", or "stopgap solution, or "temporary solution".
2. While "gap" sort of works, the word "interval", might fit better.  As AIQ said, you need to use 'between' with 'and', and not with 'to'.